# receiving data using boost library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have gone through the following article boost-asio.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp.

I wanted to modify above server so that it can accept multiple clients and receive data from the clients as well.

For accepting connection it has a handler, how and where can I put handler to receive the data? There is mechanism to recive new connection, but it does not have a mechanism to receive the data. How can i do this?

Comment: I attempted to fix the formatting of your question, please take a few minutes when writing your questions to form complete sentences with capitalization and punctuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can look for tcp server [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_server.cpp) .

And here more [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html)